# How to find the current connection count in weblogic server 10.3

Tags: connection-pooling, weblogic-10.x

Hi I need to get the current alive connections count in the connection pool in Weblogic server 10.3. Is there any way to check it in weblogic server console.

Answer (score 1):

In the console, use Services -> JDBC -> Datasources. Click the desired datasource name from the list. Then click the Monitoring tab. You should see a column called Active Connections Current Count. If not, use the 'Customize this table' option to mark this column for display in the table.